# How to prevent re-rendering page using Router Angular

Tags: angular, render

How to prevent re-rendering of whole page when I click on:

```
  <div (click)="navigateTo('important-dates')">IMPORTANT DATES</div>
```

I use

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

and my code is:

```
 navigateTo(path: string) {
    if (this.$isNotVisible.isVisible) {
      this.router.navigate([path]).then(() => {
        this.$isNotVisible.toggleVisible();
        this.$canvaOpen.set(true);
      });
     
    }
  }
```

Now my whole page reload.

```
  <div class="accomodation" ><img src="../../../assets/Accomodation-svg.svg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mainContentContent" id="contentId">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
 
  <div class="futureArrow">
    <div class="tirthLine" id="future">FUTURE!</div>
  </div>
```

but I want only re-render mainContentContent component not the whole page.